# error installing numpy via homebrew in Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I have the follow error when installing numpy via homebrew:

```
$ pip install numpy


  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types

    out = check_types(*a, **kw)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 288, in check_types

    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

I have not found any solution that works me.
I have installed XCode, python 2.7.6 (via homebrew). brew doctor says that everything is ok.

Comment: Make sure xcode command line tools are installed.

Comment: Also try `brew doctor`

Comment: command line tools are installed. brew doctor-> Your system is ready to brew

Comment: Reinstalled xcode command line tools directly from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action. Everything remains the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstall python via:

```
brew uninstall python
```

reinstall python:

```
brew install python
```

and setuptools and pip:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip
```

now,

```
pip install numpy
```

Successfully installed